# Пропало устройство вывода звука realtek high definition audio

Tags: аудио, железо

После перезагрузки компьютера пропал звук в наушниках подключённых в материнскую плату штекером. Проверил "Звук" в панели задач, но не обнаружил там устройства вывода, которое всегда там было. Так же оно не отображается в диспечере устройств. Установил новый аудиодрайвер на материнку(Asus), но ничем не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Из быстрых и примитивных методов предлагаю Вам попробовать другие наушники или колонки (если есть в наличии). Если нет, то перезагрузить с наушниками и без.
Еще можно проверить визуально пытается ли комп выдать звук, в пусковой панели нажать на "динамик" и кликнуть на изменение громкости (не плавно перетаскивать ползунок, а  кликать в сторону увеличения или уменьшения громкости) и тогда зеленый индикатор продублирует визуально в вертикальном положении. [image: Громкость]